# RadGridView detect CellClick event button

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

How can I detect which mouse button was pressed in event CellClick, or how can I detect which cell was pressed in event MouseClick.

Comment: One question... is this really DataGridView?

Comment: Sorry it's RadGridView, my bad.

Comment: No problem; I did misread your question too, so we are even :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect which cell was clicked by using Mouse Click event.

Then you have to cast sender to RadGridView, and then use CurrentCell property.

```
GridViewCellInfo dataCell = (sender as RadGridView).CurrentCell;
```

If you want to which mouse button was clicked use:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
//your code here
}
```

Comment: This returns the selected cell, which may not be the one that was right clicked on.

Comment: WTF there is no MouseClick event?

Answer (score 1):

I have written this answer thinking that you meant `DataGridView`; but this code might also be useful for `RadGridView`. What I usually do in these cases (with `DataGridView`) is relying on a global flag to coordinate two different events; just a few global flags should be OK. Sample code:

```
bool aCellWasSelected = false;
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    aCellWasSelected = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell selectedCell = null;
    if (aCellWasSelected) 
    {
       selectedCell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
       MouseButtons curButton = e.Button;
       //Do stuff with the given cell + button
    }

    aCellWasSelected = false;
}
```

NOTE: the proposed global-variable-based approach is NOT the ideal proceeding, but a practical solution pretty handy in quite a few DataGridView-related situations. If there is a direct solution, as in this case (as proposed in the other answer or, in DataGridView, the `CellMouseClick` event), you shouldn't ever use such an approach. I will let this answer as a reference anyway (for people looking for equivalent two-event-coordination situations, where no direct solution is present).

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer not to use global variables.

Comment: @bonio As said, not too much experience in RadGridView; but, at least in DataGridView, this is "required" (= the most adequate proceeding) in quite a few scenarios.