# Cannot implicitly convert type on Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

Please take a look at below codes:

```
private void testing(object sender,MouseEventArgs e){
    GridViewCellInfo testData = (sender as RadGridView).CurrentCell;
}
```

From the above code, intellisense giving me error as below

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell' 
to 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewCellInfo'
```

According the this link [RadGridView detect CellClick event button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116095/radgridview-detect-cellclick-event-button), I'm suppose to be able to write the above code. So what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like `CurrentCell` is not returning what you think it will. Try only looking for a `GridViewCell` and see if that will accomplish what you need.

```
private void testing(object sender,MouseEventArgs e){
    GridViewCell testData = (sender as RadGridView).CurrentCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GridViewCellInfo testData = (sender as RadGridView).Cells[*number of cell*];
```

See [sample](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-gridviewcellinfo.html) in telerik site.